# Bootstrap Card images are not contained perfectly around corners

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to build a portfolio with bootstrap cards where images are also required to be displayed.

Problem is that images are not contained properly within bootstrap card around corners(with class="card-img-top") like some **cards are not rounded** or some **images are not rounded but** cards are rounded(tried class="img-rounded").

Kindly zoom in on the images to see the difference. Below are some snippets (and code is given below the snippets):-

**Perfect card with image:-**
[image]

**Yellow-> difference**

**Bug-1:-**
[image]

**Bug-2:-**
[image]

**Bug-3:-**
[image]

**Bug-4:-**
[image]

Code:-

```
<%- include('partials/headHTML') %>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/tourpackageStyles.css">
    </head>
    <!-- <%- include('partials/header') %> -->

        <div class="Container">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col col-md-4">
                        <div class="card h-100">
                            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/06/05/20/24/rome-7244828_960_720.jpg" alt="" class="card-img-top">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div class="card-title">Title-1</div>
                            </div>
                            <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreffer" href="#" role="button"
                                class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary">Enquire</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col col-md-4">
                        <div class="card h-100">
                            <img src="/images/wildlife/wildlife_tour.jpg"
                                alt=""
                                class="card-img-top">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div class="card-title">Title- 2</div>
                            </div>
                            <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreffer" href="#"
                                class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary">Enquire</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3 row-cols-sm-2 gy-3">
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="card h-100">
                            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/06/05/20/24/rome-7244828_960_720.jpg" alt="" class="card-img-top">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div class="card-title">
                                    Title- 3
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="card h-100">
                            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/06/05/20/24/rome-7244828_960_720.jpg" alt="" class="card-img-top">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div class="card-title">
                                    Title- 4
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="card h-100">
                            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/06/05/20/24/rome-7244828_960_720.jpg" alt="" class="card-img-top">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div class="card-title">
                                    Title- 5
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="card h-100">
                            <img src="" alt="">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div class="card-title">
                                    Title- 6
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="card h-100">
                            <img src="" alt="">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div class="card-title">
                                    Title- 7
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="card h-100">
                            <img src="" alt="">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div class="card-title">
                                    Title- 8
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>
```

Comment: Please add the css code too, so can check the current status and we can help/fix it.

Comment: @alex It's using Bootstrap, I submitted an edit to see it when it will get accepted

Comment: @alex  No extra CSS is used, only bootstrap(CDN) is used.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to display only image while using card then place image inside card-body to achieve what you want and give card class "overflow-hidden". Because if you use "card-img-top" and then it has only border-top-left-radius and border-top-right-radius so image wouldn't be rounded on bottom.so you have to provide border-radius manually to both bottom side.

```
 <div class="card overflow-hidden">
       <div class="card-body">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="" alt="">
        </div>
 </div>
```

For more information refer official docs https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/card/